# Java with ingenico sdk app running on ingenico ICT 220/250 models, Ingenico IWL 250, Ingenico IPP320

Tags: java

I have developed a POS (Point of sale system) in java (GUI based) in which i want to manage card swiping, payment and i am looking for confirmation if ingenico SDK as being integrated with java will be supported in these Ingenico devices  (Ingenico ICT 220/250 models, Ingenico IWL 250, Ingenico IPP320.)  If not then tell me what i am missing here? How can i make a java app work on the above mentioned devices?  What's telium and its role in ingenico?

I have looked around on Ingenico and telium 2 vendors online and unable to get that answer. I have also dropped Ingenico an email about this confirmation and they haven't responded. Telium 2 has said that they don't support developer's access to devs other than north America and Canadian side.

**(I have also heard but i am not sure that java derived apps from telium do work on the above mentioned device models. Is it true?)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your question is, but I integrated ict220 with an old VFP app. It's all about communicating with the device on COM port. There is a pretty simple protocol to make basic calls like send amount to device and listen to response/confirmation/errors. In VFP we did use mscomm32.ocx to manage communication.

Answer (score 0):

the ingenico devices with the RBA (retail base application) all have java and android SDKs which you can get from the developer pages on the ingenico developer website.

the download will contain an RBA_SDK.jar along with an iConnect_eft.jar.

android will also have an Android_SDK_Adapter.jar

Comment: have integrated igenico device using Java? I'm talking hardware device integration where java can communicate with Igenico device